# Adding select to my contact from scripts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Once my friend gave me this contact form script, but now i want to add a select option to it but i don't know how. I tried but it doesn't work. Here is my html and js code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tofkmkw/)):

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact-form" class="wniosek">
                            <div class="success"> Wiadomość została wysłana<br>
                            <strong>Odpowiemy wkrótce.</strong> </div>
                            <fieldset>
                                <label class="name rel col-sm-12">
                                    <span class="inp">
                                        <input type="text" value="Imię i nazwisko" class="col-sm-12">
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="email rel col-sm-12">
                                    <span class="inp">
                                        <input type="text" value="E-mail" class="col-sm-12">
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="phone rel col-sm-12">
                                    <span class="inp">
                                        <input type="text" value="Telefon" class="col-sm-12">
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="dropdown rel col-sm-12">
                                        <select name="dropdown" style="width:100%;"> 
                                            <option value="kfirm">Kredyt Firmowy</option>
                                            <option value="kgot">Kredyt Gotówkowy</option>
                                            <option value="kobro">Kredyt Obrotowy</option>
                                            <option value="phipo">Pożyczka Hipoteczna</option>
                                            <option value="khipo">Kredyt Hipoteczny</option>
                                            <option value="kkonso">Kredyt Konsolidacyjny</option>
                                            <option value="kinwest">Kredyt Inwestycyjny</option>
                                            <option value="ksamocho">Kredyt Samochodowy</option>
                                            <option value="leasing">Leasing</option>
                                        </select>
                                </label>
                                <label class="message rel col-sm-12">
                                    <span class="text_a">
                                        <textarea class="col-sm-12" style="height:300px;">Wiadomość</textarea>
                                    </span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="buttons-wrapper"><a class="button2 btn btn-white" href="#" data-type="reset"><span>Wyczyść</span></a><a class="button2 btn btn-white" href="#" data-type="submit"><span>Wyślij</span></a></div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//forms
;(function($){
    $.fn.forms=function(o){
        return this.each(function(){
            var th=$(this)
                ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                    errorCl:'error',
                    emptyCl:'empty',
                    invalidCl:'invalid',
                    notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                    successCl:'success',
                    successShow:'4000',
                    mailHandlerURL:'wyslijWniosek.php',                 
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea',
                    controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                    validate:true,
                    rx:{
                        ".state":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                        ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".fax":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".message":{rx:/.{20}/,target:'textarea'}
                    },
                    preFu:function(){
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var label=$(this),
                                inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                defVal=inp.val(),
                                trueVal=(function(){
                                            var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                            return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                        })()
                            trueVal!=defVal
                                &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                            label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                            inp
                                .bind('focus',function(){
                                    inp.val()==defVal
                                        &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur',function(){
                                    _.validateFu(label)
                                    if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                        inp.val(defVal)
                                        ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                                })
                                .bind('keyup',function(){
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                        &&_.validateFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                        })
                        _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                    },
                    isRequired:function(el){                            
                        return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                    },
                    isValid:function(el){                           
                        var ret=true
                        $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                            if(el.is(k))
                                ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                        })
                        return ret                          
                    },
                    isEmpty:function(el){
                        var tmp
                        return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                    },
                    validateFu:function(el){                            
                        el.each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                                ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                                ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                                ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                            if(empty&&req)
                                _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            if(!empty)
                                if(valid)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                else
                                    _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                        })
                    },
                    getValFromLabel:function(label){
                        var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                            ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                        return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                    }
                    ,submitFu:function(){
                        _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:{
                                    name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                    email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                    phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                    fax:_.getValFromLabel($('.fax',_.form)),
                                    state:_.getValFromLabel($('.state',_.form)),
                                    message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    _.showFu()
                                }
                            })          
                    },
                    showFu:function(){
                        _.success.slideDown(function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                _.success.slideUp()
                                _.form.trigger('reset')
                            },_.successShow)
                        })
                    },
                    controlsFu:function(){
                        $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                            th
                                .bind('click',function(){
                                    _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                    return false
                                })
                        })
                    },
                    showErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                    },
                    hideErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    showEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                        _.hideErrorFu(label)
                    },
                    hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    init:function(){
                        _.form=_.me                     
                        _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                        _.preFu()

                        _.controlsFu()

                        _.form
                            .bind('submit',function(){
                                if(_.validate)
                                    _.submitFu()
                                else
                                    _.form[0].submit()
                                return false
                            })
                            .bind('reset',function(){
                                _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                _.labels.each(function(){
                                    var th=$(this)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                    _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                })
                            })
                        _.form.trigger('reset')
                    }
                }
            _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
            typeof o=='object'
                &&$.extend(_,o)
        })
    }
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.wniosek').forms({
        ownerEmail:'#'
    })
})
```

and here php code:

```
<?php
$owner_email = "<mail here>"; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<    tutaj wpisz adres email na który mają byc wysyłane maile
$headers = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
$subject = 'Wiadomość ze strony internetowej';
$subject = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";
$messageBody = "";


if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Imię i nazwisko: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
$mailnadawcy = $_POST['email'];
    $messageBody .= '<p>Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n"; 
}else{
    $headers = '';
}
if($_POST['state']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Telefon: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}    
if($_POST['fax']!='nope'){        
    $messageBody .= '<p>Fax: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
}
if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '<p>Treść: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
}

if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
    $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
}
mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers);


?>
```

I want my select option to be in a mail message :)

Comment: What happened when you try to add it ?

Comment: Well your select has a name, and this name you use in $_POST['NAME'] to get its value. You can copy one if statement and just change the name to your select name.

Comment: I tried to add it also in js but when i did that, my contact form didn't send anything

Comment: We do not have your js code so we can not say. Yet basically you do not need any js code for this. Just html select with a name.

Comment: Added your code inline for easier access and preservation.

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty much as you have the other options:

if($_POST['op']!='nope'){
    $messageBody .= '

Telefon: ' . $_POST['op'] . '

' . "\n";
    $messageBody .= '
' . "\n";
}

And in the html:

```
<select name=" op">
    <option value="option1">This is option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">  This is option 2</option>
</select>
```